# HtmlAgilityPack - Keep text position upon removal of node

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

When I remove a node (with `keepGrandChildren`) that has both text and child nodes inside, the text  is pushed all the way after the child nodes, rather than stay in its original location.

**Example:**

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"
<span id='first'>
    This text comes first.
    <span id='second'>This text comes second.</span>
</span>");

var node = doc.GetElementbyId("first");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

The output that I get is:

```
    <span id='second'>This text comes second.</span>
        this text comes first.
```

Instead of:

```
    this text comes first.
    <span id='second'>This text comes second.</span>
```

**Is there any way of removing a node using `keepGrandChildren` without the text inside getting pushed towards the end?**
I want to conserve *absolute* order and make sure that no text or nodes change their original position, otherwise the document will be ruined.

*Edit:*
I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6.0` and `.NET 4.0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [know issue](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/9113) in the HtmlAgilityPack. The following code should solve the problem:

```
public static void RemoveChildKeepGrandChildren(HtmlNode parent, HtmlNode oldChild)
{
    if (oldChild.ChildNodes != null)
    {
        HtmlNode previousSibling = oldChild.PreviousSibling;
        foreach (HtmlNode newChild in oldChild.ChildNodes)
        {
            parent.InsertAfter(newChild, previousSibling);
            previousSibling = newChild;  // Missing line in HtmlAgilityPack
        }
    }
    parent.RemoveChild(oldChild);
}
```

Comment: A simple test does show that this code does what I wanted, and it's MUCH faster than the semi-hacky way I came up with. I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: **Update:** This solution works perfectly and efficiently. Thanks!